# Vectors and ClassicThesis (with eulermath)

Tags: classicthesis

I use ClassicThesis with the `eulermath` option. I redefined the standard command for vectors as

```
\renewcommand{\vec}{\mathbf}
```

The problem is that that the letter written whit `mathbf` is completely different to the letter written in `eulermath`. How can I fix this problem?

This is a MWS:

```
\documentclass[%
    10pt,%
    a4paper,%
    onside,%
    headinclude,%
    footinclude,%
    BCOR5mm,%
    captions=tableheading]%
        {scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\vec}{\mathbf}

\usepackage[%
    nochapters,%
    beramono,%
    eulermath,%
    pdfspacing,%
    listings]%
        {classicthesis}

\author{Author}
\title{Test}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

As you can see, there is a big difference:
\[
   a \neq \vec{a}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You get bold Euler with `\mathbold`: Section 4.1.3 in the documentation of `eulervm`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `eulermath` option loads the `eulervm` package, which distinguishes the standard `\mathbf` command from its own command `\mathbold` which uses Euler Bold.

So the answer is

```
\renewcommand{\vec}{\mathbold}
```

If you want a redefinition that's independent of the `eulermath` option, you can say

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@eulermath}}
  {\renewcommand{\vec}{\mathbold}}
  {\renewcommand{\vec}{\mathbf}}
```

[image]

<sub>Sorry for the non spaced colon, but I can't stand it. :)</sub>

Comment: Thank you! =). (The spaced colon is obtained with `french` option in `babel` package... ;) ).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

`\mathbf` is the math access for the *text bold font*.

If you load `bm` package *after* the euler fonts are set up you can use `\bm` as shown above .

```
\documentclass[%
    10pt,%
    a4paper,%
    onside,%
    headinclude,%
    footinclude,%
    BCOR5mm,%
    captions=tableheading]%
        {scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[french]{babel}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\vec}{\mathbf}

\usepackage[%
    nochapters,%
    beramono,%
    eulermath,%
    pdfspacing,%
    listings]%
        {classicthesis}

\usepackage{bm}
\author{Author}
\title{Test}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle



As you can see, there is a big difference:
\[
   a \neq \vec{a} \bm{a}
\]

\end{document}
```